# NameError when doing a basic input

Tags: python, python-3.x, nameerror

I have a super basic question, but I'm just starting to learn python. My script:

```
print('What is your name?')
person = input("Enter name: ")
print("Hello ", person)
```

is returning an error: `NameError: name 'Bob' is not defined`.

I have basically just copied and pasted what was from the tutorial at this point, but it still doesn't work unless I put the name in quotation marks. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are using python3? This looks like python2 where you should use `raw_input`.

Comment: This code just works fine. Can you please copy _the code_ you are using?

Comment: I swear this is the code verbatim. Also Im writing it in python3, Im running it with python launcher 3.3.5.

Comment: This can't be the full code that you are using, as a `NameError` means that you are trying to access a variable that cannot be accessed in that scope. As you never reference a variable called `Bob`, either that code or that error is false.

Comment: Try closing your session and re-entering the three lines above in a fresh prompt (assuming you are using an interactive prompt for this). Something must be persisting from a previous attempt.

Comment: Make sure, you are running Python 3. Add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` at the very top of the module if you use pylauncher. Add `import sys; print(sys.version)`, to see the version.

Comment: @user3430541 Are you typing `python yourfile.py` or `python3 yourfile.py`? Or are you just typing `yourfile.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work perfectly fine in Python 3. However, in Py2 it will throw a `NameError` as there are differences between `input()` and `raw_input()`. Essentially, `input()` in Python 2 is the same as `eval(raw_input(""Enter name: "))`, meaning that it will attempt to run the `input`ed code as Python.

In Python 3, `raw_input()` is no more, and `input()` operates the way you are expecting it to here: Print a line, accept input, and assign it in string format to a variable.

Comment: The `print` function is varadic. So OP's last line works fine.

Comment: @Hyperboreus you are correct...

Comment: @Hyperboreus changed to reflect actual issue...

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. It's still not working on my computer, I'm definitely using python 3.3.5 launcher. I am on a mac if that changes anything. But the really interesting part is that if I change it to raw_input() then it works. Ill keep looking into it. Thanks again

Comment: @user3430541 if `raw_input()` works, then somehow you're using Python 2. Try restarting your interpreter, then running `import sys; print(sys.version)` and see what comes up.

Comment: `input()` in Python 2 is `eval(raw_input())`, not `exec`. You could just say that `raw_input()` is renamed to `input()` in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

You simply are not using Python 3. In Python 2, [`input()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#input) works differently; see this excerpt from the docs.

> Equivalent to `eval(raw_input(prompt))`.

So, when you type `Bob` without quotation marks, you are basically saying `eval(Bob)`. With quotes it is `eval("Bob")`. [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) does not exist in Python 3, so it will not be defined if you are running with Python 3.

Make sure that you are running your file with Python 3:

- Type `which python` and `which python3` to make sure you have both.
- Run `python` and `python3` and see which versions you are running when the python shell opens.
- You can check the version of Python which is running your code by doing `import sys; print(sys.version)`.
- Run your code via `python3 yourfile.py`.
- As J.F. Sebastian notes, you should add `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the very first line of your file. Chances are, you either wrote `#! /usr/bin/env python` which on OS X is 2.7.x (I think it's 2.7.2, and I think `python` is a symlink to the `python27` binary) and are running your file just by typing its name, or you are running it through `python`.